# Flutter - passing data from child to parent and to another child

Tags: android, flutter, mobile, dart, constructor

I got a class Restrictions and 3 childs.

I want to pass data from CountryDropDown (and from FieldDropDown class which looks almost same, and from DateSelector class but thats maybe later) class to Restrictions and then to UserOffers (with updating List by tapping a button).

For now I can only define variable in Restrictions class and pass it like this. All on Strings.

**Restrictions class:**

```
  String selectedCountry = "Argentina"; 
             ...

                    children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20),
                  child: FieldDropDown(),
                ),
                Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20),
                  child: CountryDropDown(
                  ), 
        ...

            Container(
              child: UserOffers(
                country: selectedCountry,
                field: selectedField,
                ),
            ),
```

**UserOffers class:**

```
class UserOffers extends StatefulWidget {

  final String country;
  final String field;

  UserOffers({
    this.country,
    this.field
  }); ...
```

**CountryDropDown class:**

```
  static String value;
  static String selected;

  @override
  void initState() {
    selected = _CountryDropDownState.selected;
    super.initState();
  } ...
   ... ]
        .map((label) => DropdownMenuItem(
              child: Text(label),
              value: label,
            ))
        .toList(),
    onChanged: (value) {
      setState(() => selected = value);
      print(selected);
    },
  ),
),
)
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your problem is related to the [state management](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/intro) in Flutter. There are a few approaches that solve this issue, for example:

- inherited widget
- provider
- bloc
- redux

If you want to learn more check the [official doumentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options).

Comment: Do you think, it will work, when i will get data from dropdowns with provider and then update my list via constructor and setstate?

Comment: No, yo don't need to pass your data via constructor and use setState. Wrap you list with `ChangeNotifierProvider` and you will be able to rebuild it whenever new data arrives.